# TeXstudio: Change external PDF viewer command to open pdf from sub-directory?

Tags: texstudio

Under `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands` I changed PdfLateX to use the `-output-directory=tex` option. I checked `Show Advanced Options` in the bottom right corner and set all additional search paths under `Build` to the used directory name.

Everything works (I can compile to PDF and preview it in the internal PDF viewer) but I don't know how I should change the `External PDF Viewer` command so that it opens the PDF from the subdirectory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me (on Windows 7, note that I use PDFViewer, not Adobe Reader):

External PDF Viewer command (where 'build' is my custom output directory):

```
"C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" ".\build\?m.pdf"
```

Notice the quotes around the argument; they are needed if there are any spaces in the file/sub-directory name.

Answer (score 7):

I think a more generic solution would be to set the `External PDF Viewer` value in `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands` to:

```
"YOUR PDF VIEWER ADDRESS"  "?am.pdf"
```

For example mine is:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat DC/Acrobat/Acrobat.exe"  "?am.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! Could you please explain what does `"?am.pdf"` stand for?

Comment: For me, this auto-translated to main.pdf, so I think it means whichever PDF is open when you click the button.