# Configuring Foxit as external PDF viewer in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, windows, viewers

Sorry if this is a duplicate from other questions but I wasn't able to solve my problem referring to [this article here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272151/texstudio-change-external-pdf-viewer-command-to-open-pdf-from-sub-directory) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/058fc149/).

I'm trying to configure FoxitReader 8.0 as default external viewer for TeXstudio (2.11.2) on Windows 10.

I tried <kbd>Options</kbd>
 --> <kbd>Configure TeXstudio</kbd>
 --> <kbd>Commands</kbd>
 --> <kbd>External PDF Viewer</kbd>
 --> <kbd>C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe</kbd>

and

<kbd>Options</kbd>
 --> <kbd>Configure TeXstudio</kbd>
 --> <kbd>Build</kbd>
 --> <kbd>[add user command]</kbd>
 --> <kbd>txs:///view-pdf-external</kbd>

but I still get

> `Error: Could not start the command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Doesn't Foxit Reader  lock  .pdf files, just like Acrobat Reader? It's a huge  problem when you compile the same code multiple times.

Comment: Cannot answer, but suggest: Quotes around file "path/name"? Change backslashes to forward slashes? Perhaps instead use Foxit Reader Portable, in your home directory?

Comment: I'm not recommending Foxit as it does not support SyncTeX. Instead use SumatraPDF viewer

Comment: try to accosiate `.pdf` files with Foxit. This can be done by following these steps `control panel --> programs --> default programs --> associate a file type or protocol with a program`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: see if adding quotation marks to the path changes anything: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" %.pdf`

Comment: @naphaneal, thanks that worked. silly of me. I'll also try SumatraPDF viewer

Comment: @Bernard: You are right, but this behavior can be changed by calling Foxit as `FoxitReader.exe <document> /A nolock=1`

Comment: @PhilippImhof how do I do that?

Comment: @Philipp Imhof: Does it also have synctex capabilities?

Comment: @Bernard: I do not know and could not find anything about it in a quick online search. As I currently do not have access to my windows machine, I cannot test it. But I do not remember having found any option in Foxit Reader, so I guess it does not.

Comment: @simone: I do not work with TeX-Studio, but I guess you just set the external viewer to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /A nolock=1`. I suppose TeX-Studio will then just add the filename to that command.

Comment: For those wanting to use okular like me, you can use ```Configure TeXstudio --> Commands -->External PDF viewer: okular --unique %.pdf#src:@?c:m.tex``` source: http://diegotorquemada-latex.blogspot.com/2017/03/texstudio-dvi-ps-pdf-chain.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution using @naphaneal's and @PhilippImhof's comments:

In

`Options` --> `Configure TeXstudio` --> `Commands` --> `External PDF Viewer`

change this

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe`

to this

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" %.pdf`

or this

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" %.pdf /A nolock=1`

to avoid Foxit Reader to lock pdf files.

Comment: Small edit, `%.pdf` won't cut it. Instead use `"?am.pdf"` So, this works for me: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" "?am.pdf" /A nolock=1`

Comment: The exe file is now: `FoxitPDFReader.exe`

Comment: For the `FoxitPDFEditor` this works for me `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Foxit Software/Foxit PDF Editor/FoxitPDFEditor.exe" "%.pdf"  /A nolock=1 /.pdf`