# Using Texstudio on Second Screen ( by extend mode in Windows 10)

Tags: texstudio

My laptop screen is small, So I want to use TexStudio by extending to 2nd screen. There is no problem other software (Matlab, Maple etc.)

But in TexStudio, I think there is a scaling problem, so all writings are nested. It is not readable. Please find the following picture.
How can we solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: you could use an external pdf viewer instead. You will save more than 1/3 of the whole space ;) For instance you could look over: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272151/texstudio-change-external-pdf-viewer-command-to-open-pdf-from-sub-directory. However, IMHO, the answer to this question is primariy opinion-based.

Comment: Using an external PDF viewer is a good idea, but be aware that some PDF viewers will put a lock on your PDF file. This means you won't be able to produce an updated version of the PDF with TeX as long as it is open in the external viewer. You need to find one that will automatically reload the PDF and show you the updated version when it is produced, instead of blocking it's creation. You could look at SumatraPDF, Okular, or Evince, depending on your OS.

Comment: Readers please Note it is the EDITOR NOT VIEWER at fault

Answer (score 4):

Could you unlock the pdf viewer and put it on the second screen ? i work like that every day and never had that scaling issue ...

[image: to unlock the viewer]

Comment: Stupid me was just looking if something like this is possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[image]
The most common cause for lettering issues in the editor (too small or too large) is due to the user zoom setting if that is combined with other scaling issues it may be producing odd effects.

So the first thing to try is use **CTRL and the scroll wheel** to adjust your zoom to a reasonable level.

The most likely cause when using dual screens for a mismatch in dpi settings is
the system trying to auto match for the differences Preferably both screens should be set to 100%. In this case there are a few advanced editor settings so try this combination.

[image]

Finally if you messed about with other font settings you may need to reset
so try this first **beware** it  may remove some of your custom settings so it is a good idea to **save profile first** that is two lines above on the menu (you can then reload if necessary later)

[image]

Comment: Change the display settings in Windows (text size 100% for both monitors) as per the suggestion of User170179 "Preferably both screens should be set to 100%" - this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Next to your *texstudio.exe* place a file *qt.conf* containing

> [Platforms] 
>   WindowsArguments = dpiawareness=1

this fixed the problem for me two years ago. Unfortunately, I don't remember where I found the solution. There might however be a different problem that comes from this, described [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1066).

Comment: Worked like a charm for me on version 4.2.2.