# Text and text cursor moving within TexStudio editor as I write (on extended monitor)

Tags: texstudio

This may seem a very basic question but as I write in TexStudio, the text and text cursor are moving as if the text were being formatted or centred continuously.

I am not in insert text mode and have reset the TexStudio settings a couple of times and fully restarted.

Does anyone recognise this problem?

Edit:

I have found that this only happens why I have TexStudio open on a second extended monitor, does anyone know how to align the settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. It was a repeat of a different issue when extending to a second screen. One screen was set to 100% view and the other 125%, setting them equal removed the issue.

This is outlined well in this answer on this site [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475606/using-texstudio-on-second-screen-by-extend-mode-in-windows-10),